# How to inject request headers before initializing a webapp2.WSGIApplication

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, wsgi, webapp2

Assuming the following AppEngine/webapp2 code:

```
import webapp2

# insert header injection code here...

class HelloWebapp2(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('Hello, webapp2!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', HelloWebapp2),
], debug=True)
```

How can I inject request headers before app is initialized/called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided to just extend `webapp2.RequestHandler` and create a base class for all other handlers that we use in our application.  In this base class, we override the `dispatch` method, and inject headers.  This makes those headers available to instances of any classes that derive from this base class.

```
class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def dispatch(self):
    // inject headers here (self.request.headers)
    super(BaseHandler, self).dispatch() 

class Page|SecurePage|APIEndPoint|ETC(BaseHandler):
  // ...
```

Comment: isn't it better to use `webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)` in the overridden dispatch method than the `super` dispatching?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know what the difference is between the two options.  What have you heard/read?

Comment: This is in the docs:             ```# Dispatch the request.
            webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)```

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie and @threed, other parts of the docs use `super`, see https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/handlers.html#overriding-dispatch

Answer (score 1):

Consider using some form of wsgi middle ware, which your wrapp `app` with.

From wikipedia   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface Under Specification overview

> wsgi middleware implements both sides of the API so that it can
>   intermediate between a WSGI server and a WSGI application: the
>   middleware acts as an application from some WSGI server's point of
>   view and as a server from some WSGI application's point of view. A
>   "middleware" component can perform such functions as: Routing a
>   request to different application objects based on the target URL,
>   after changing the environment variables accordingly. Allowing
>   multiple applications or frameworks to run side-by-side in the same
>   process Load balancing and remote processing, by forwarding requests
>   and responses over a network Perform content postprocessing, such as
>   applying XSLT stylesheets

See article WSGI and WSGI Middleware is Easy http://be.groovie.org/2005/10/07/wsgi_and_wsgi_middleware_is_easy.html

I use middleware wrappers for a number of things in appengine.

Session management, event propagation - (ie send event on new session, new login).
authorization (which is different authentication).  Though I have never used webapp(2) it functions in the same way and is wsgi compliant.

Comment: would be nice to have the link to the quoted text as well.. :)